# In VScode, how do I open a file from the line it's being imported on?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm `import`ing various items from a file in vscode. The module exists, but seems to be missing some of the items. I can see the module definitely exists on the filesystem, and vscode even shows me the file name:

[image]

I'd like to open the file directly from where it's imported, using the same logic VScode itself uses to import the module. I would have thought right clicking would allow me to do this ('Go to implementation') sounds like it would open the file, but it doesn't do anything.

Obviously I could open a shell and start `code` pointing to that file, but that's a workaround rather than an actual solution.

**How do I open a file being imported in vscode?**

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+Click? But I'd expect "Go to definition" to work as well.

Comment: Ah @bergi you're right. I thought 'implementation' was where something was implemented (ie, written as code) and 'definition' was where it was being used as a variable. Ie seems where the code is made is actually the actually not the 'implementation' but the 'definition'. If you add an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

- Right Click and then select "Go to Definition" (not 'go to implementation' as you were using)
- Select type and then press F12
- Ctrl (cmd on Mac) + left mouse click

I like the last shortcut. It's easy and reachable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the module you are viewing is a commonJS module.
You could create or add the following settings in `.jsonconfig` file.

Set/add entry "module": "CommonJS" or set "module": "Node16"

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "module": "Node16"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
, "public/src"  ]
}
```

OR

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "module": "CommonJS"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
, "public/src"  ]
}
```

Hope this helps